# ClientContext is null for HOST web in AppInstalled

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver

I'm trying to create remote event receiver that is attached to library in host web.

I used azure service bus for debugging and almost everything worked out nicely. Removing of receiver did not work, but that is something that just supposedly does not work in debug mode ever.

I'm following the official(?) sample from https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP and getting host web context with this command

```
ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false)
```

After some googling I found this blog post http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/07/remote-event-receivers-on-host-web-ClientContext.html . From it it looks like it should without app-only model. Which i would really like not to use.

My endpoint for deployed RER is in Azure and is HTTPS, not HTTP.

Can anybody with experience with remote event receivers help me out pleaase?

Answer (score 0):

So i used remote debugging of azure web app in visual studio. It is needed to publish app in debugging configuration and found out that my endpoint is in different domain then one i specified during app registration. That is what bothers sharepoint online.

But i guess there are some valid security reasons.

Anyway there is no way to change the domain of registered app and no way to use already used client id and secret even after deleting app registration.